# Setting Timezone for Celery Flower Displays Wrong Time

Tags: python, docker, celery, flower

I'm running a celery worker and flower in two separate containers using docker.

The host machine's timezone is set to `America/Denver`.

The celery worker has the following timezone-related configurations:

```
app = Celery('app', broker=RABBITMQ_BROKER_URL)
app.conf.enable_utc = False
app.conf.timezone = 'America/Denver'
```

I've tried setting the timezone for the container running flower a couple of different ways, but the datetime stamps displayed for tasks are off by 12 hours in the flower UI.

I've tried setting the timezone for flower using the following methods:

Set the `TZ` environment variable for the container to `America/Denver`
Running an interactive terminal with the container and then followed the directions from [Setting the timezone - Alpine Linux](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_the_timezone)

When I change the timezone, it change the datetime stamps for the tasks, but as I said they're off by 12 hours and I'm not sure why....

The image below for the `Received` and Started` columns show times between 3AM (03:00:00) and 4AM (04:00:00), but I would expect to see times between 3PM (15:00:00) and 4PM (16:00:00)

Thanks in advance for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your container timezone, by default it uses `UTC`.

```
ENV TZ=America/Denver
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Include this is your Dockerfile other than setting time later.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not help.